# How does "import" statement will work in server side rendering using react js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

When we are trying to import file inside node js server file, import statement is getting error. How to use es6 in node js server file ?

What are the dependencies need to install ?

Answer (score 1):

It's common to use babel (@babel/core, @babel/preset-env and maybe @babel/node depending on requirements) to use imports.

And a babel config similar to:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "8"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

With later versions of node you can run `node --experimental-modules index.mjs`  You need to use the .mjs extension or it won't work (not without extra configuration anyway).